# React: Append component animations on local and redux state updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a component that renders an animation on every local and redux state update. Local state is updated on a button click and it also makes an ajax request to a remote server to update that an user clicked the button. I update local state on every click like so:

```
 const [selfAnimations, setAnimations] = useState<AnimationRenders>(initialAnimationState);
const onButtonClickCallback = () => {
    makeRemoteAjaxCall();
    selfAnimations.localEventsCount += 1;
    selfAnimations.animationsToRender.push(Date.now);
    setAnimations(selfAnimations);
};
```

I update the data coming in from remote server like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (animationDataCount && animationDataCount > 0) {
            const {
                updatedLocalEventsCount,
                updatedAnimations,
            } = filterDedupedLocalEvents(selfAnimations, animationDataCount);
            setAnimations({
                localEventsCount: updatedLocalEventsCount,
                animationsToRender: updatedAnimations,
            });
        }
    }, [animationDataCount]);
```

I render a div with a component I created:

```
<div classNames={...}>
    <AnimationContainer numberOfAnimations={selfAnimations.animationsToRender.length} />
</div>
<div className={...}>
   <MyButton ... />
</div>
```

On client side, data is received on regular intervals. My AnimationContainer component can render any number of received animations. However, everytime a user clicks the button or client recieves remote data it updates the state and drops previous animations. Looking online I could delay the rerender with css but the behavior I need is to append to existing animations on state updates. Is there a mechanism that I could use for that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood how react renders. React does not necessarily create a new child component and unmount the old component on props/state updates. In my case, instead of storing counts of what needed to be rendered, I need to store distinct keys for what needed to be rendered, because even if the AnimationContainer  component receives updates from props, if it only received counts, then it may not trigger rerenders because the count can be the same. I got around this by implementing the props of localEvents as an array of `timestamps: number[]`. By passing down timestamps to AnimationContainer and refactoring AnimationContainer to check props update and store into state of animations in middle of rendering and a queue of animations to render, I was able to create a component that can receive and continually renders animations based on events.